# Click event for multiple dynamically generated elements with the same class name to hide and unhide other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a JavaScript or jquery function that binds a click event to dynamically or server generated element with the class name (manage-inventory). The function should perform the following :

- When clicked, it should toggle a bootstrap class (d-none) on its next sibling element(manage-inventory-card). The key is here is to remove the default "d-none" class in order to make the "manage-inventory-card" element show
- When the element with the class name (manage-inventory) is clicked again, it should add the class "d-none" back to the "manage-inventory-card" element in order to hide it.
- If any part of the page except the "manage-inventory-card" is clicked, the "manage-inventory-card", the class name "d-none" should be added back to it.
- Clicking another dynamically generated element with the same class (manage-inventory) should close the previous "manage-inventory-card" if still open by closing it with the addition of class "d-none".
- The event should work on only one instance of "manage-inventory" and "manage-inventory-card" at a time. Clicking one should not make it work on all others at the same time. There can only be a running instance

Below is the HTML code when it is dynamically generated by the server

The code only works for toggling of the "d-none" class when it is clicked. I don't know how to write the one that hides it back by adding "d-none" to the currently opened "manage-investment-card" when another element "manage-inventory" element is clicked and also write the code that closes it when any part of the page is clicked. Thank you

```js
$(document)
  .find(".manage-inventory")
  .each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      $(this)
        .next()
        .toggleClass("d-none");
    });
  });
```

```css
.d-none {display: none !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  N30,000.00
  <span class="manage-inventory">here</span>
  <div class="position-absolute manage-inventory-card d-none">
    <a class="edit">Edit</a>
    <a class="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  N30,000.00
  <span class="manage-inventory">here</span>
  <div class="position-absolute manage-inventory-card d-none">
    <a class="edit">Edit</a>
    <a class="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit the snippet I made and add CSS to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to delegate.

I am delegating from document because you want to check all clicks on document

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  var $tgt = $(e.target);
  if ($tgt.is(".manage-inventory")) {
    var $thisChild = $tgt.next();
    $(".manage-inventory-card").not($thisChild).addClass("d-none");
    $thisChild.toggleClass("d-none");
  } else {
    $(".manage-inventory-card").addClass("d-none");
  }
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  N30,000.00
  <span class="manage-inventory">here</span>
  <div class="position-absolute manage-inventory-card d-none">1
    <a class="edit">Edit</a>
    <a class="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  N30,000.00
  <span class="manage-inventory">here</span>
  <div class="position-absolute manage-inventory-card d-none">2
    <a class="edit">Edit</a>
    <a class="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```